# How to add a custom view programmatically on a custom cell?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, custom-controls

I have a question that is perhaps very basic.
I`m building a custom cell, without a Xib file, all programmatically. In my CustomHell.m file I have basically only two methods: initWithStyle and layoutSubviews.
I have managed to add programmatically some labels and a button. Now I wish to add a specific custom view - FacebookLikeView (https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView) - but I have no idea how to do it.
This is the code in my "initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

```
    //StoreName Label
    storeName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    storeName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    storeName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 16]; //12
    storeName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    storeName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    //checkIn Button
    checkInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    checkInButton.frame = CGRectMake(203,10,86,25);
    [checkInButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check-In.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkInButton addTarget:self.nextResponder action:@selector(addCheckin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    checkInButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    //FACEBOOK
    facebookLikeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    facebookLikeButton.frame = CGRectMake(169,40,119,25);

    [self.contentView addSubview:storeName];
    [self.contentView addSubview:storeAddress];
    [self.contentView addSubview:subtitle];
    [self.contentView addSubview:checkInButton];
    [self.contentView addSubview:facebookLikeButton];
    //[self.contentView addSubview:likeButton];
return self;
```

And this is my layoutSubviews:

```
[super layoutSubviews];
CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

storeName.frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+10, 15, 190, 20);
storeAddress.frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+10, 42, 200, 40); 
subtitle.frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+10, 77, 280, 30);
likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+199, 42, 50, 20);
```

The header file looks like this:

```
#import "FacebookLikeView.h"
@interface CustomCellHead : UITableViewCell
{
FacebookLikeView *likeButton;

UIButton *facebookLikeButton;
UIButton *checkInButton;
UILabel *storeName;
UILabel *storeAddress;
UILabel *subtitle;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) FacebookLikeView *likeButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *checkInButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *storeName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *storeAddress;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *subtitle;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self addSubview: storeName]` instead of [self.contentView addSubview: storeName]

Comment: This didn’t seem to work. However, I worked around the issue by using a XIB file and connecting FacebookLikeView through IB.